# Identifying both decimals and integers in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to extract both decimal numbers and integers in a string. I am in halfway.

My code is:

```
$str = 'In My Cart : +11 -12 4577 012 4.5 9 +0.1 -4.9 345.876 0 items';
print_r($str);
echo "</br>";
preg_match_all('!\+*\-*(\d+)!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

It returns integers correctly but it splits decimal values into two values. Also, my output returns in array(array()) format instead of just array().

How can I also extract decimal values correctly and output in array() format?

Output:

> User Input: In My Cart : +11 -12 4577 012 4.5 9 +0.1 -4.9 345.876 0 items
>   Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => +11 [1] => -12 [2] => 4577 [3] => 012 [4] => 4 [5] => 5 [6] => 9 [7] => +0 [8] => 1 [9] => -4 [10] => 9 [11] => 345 [12] => 876 [13] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 12 [2] => 4577 [3] => 012 [4] => 4 [5] => 5 [6] => 9 [7] => 0 [8] => 1 [9] => 4 [10] => 9 [11] => 345 [12] => 876 [13] => 0 ) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

The number (integer or float) will be in group 1.

Comment: But now integers are not included in the output.   Output : User Input: In My Cart : +11 -12 4577 012 4.5 9 +0.1 -4.9 345.876 0 items
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 4.5 [1] => +0.1 [2] => -4.9 [3] => 345.876 ) )

Comment: @user37894: a `?` is missing in the middle of `))`.

Comment: @user37894: Add a `?` at the end of the non capture group. See my edit.